# tkz arrow shows up doubled

Tags: tkz-euclide

When I use the `tkz arrow` option to `\tkzDrawArc` twice, the first arrowhead gets doubled.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (-3,-1) rectangle (3,3);
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,2/0/R,-2/0/L}
  \tkzDrawArc[tkz arrow={stealth[scale=1.5] at .25},
  tkz arrow={stealth[scale=1.5] at .75}](O,R)(L)
  \tkzDrawSegment[tkz arrow={stealth[scale=1.5] at .25},
  tkz arrow={stealth[scale=1.5] at .75}](L,R) 
    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I add that the reason I am not using `tkz arrows` is because it doesn't appear to be configurable, and arrowheads are too big.

[image]

Comment: Personally I prefer to modify the styles outside the plots because `TikZ` and tkz-euclide` allow it. I find the code more readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrows in tkz-euclide it is the decoration part. The main goal is the construction of geometrical figures. In this decoration part, `TikZ` takes a preponderant place and it is necessary to use more often the options of `TikZ`. The problem here is that `tkz arrows is proposed to place an arrow on each segment of a path.

So in some cases you have to go through `TikZ` and know a lot of its options.

The path to represent a circle is composed of four quadrants and `tkz arrows` allows to place 4 arrows on each quadrant here for a half circle you can expect 2 arrows.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\tikzset{tkz arrows/.style= 
 {postaction={on each path={tkz arrow={Stealth[scale=1,black]}}}}}

\begin{document}
  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 3/0/B, -3/0/C} 
\tkzDrawSemiCircle[tkz arrows,thin](A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have kept `scale=1` here for the following explanation. In `TikZ`, some objects have their size depending on the thickness of the line. You must have the same thickness here for arcs, circles etc.

I have added `thin`. I have to modify the `tkz-euclide.cfg` file because I left different thicknesses for some objects.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tikzset{tkz arrows/.style= 
 {postaction={on each path={tkz arrow={Stealth[scale=1,black]}}}}}

\begin{document}
  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 3/0/B, -3/0/C} 
\tkzDrawSemiCircle[tkz arrows,thin](A,B)
\tkzDrawSegments[tkz arrows,thin](C,A A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It is also possible to place a single arrow with `tkz arrow` on each segment

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tikzset{tkz arrows/.style= 
 {postaction={on each path={tkz arrow={Stealth[scale=1,black]}}}}}

\begin{document}
  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 3/0/B, -3/0/C} 
\tkzDrawSemiCircle[tkz arrows,thin](A,B)
\tkzDrawSegments[tkz arrow={Stealth[scale=1]},thin](C,A A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tikzset{tkz arrows/.style= 
    {semithick, black,
     postaction={on each path={tkz arrow={Stealth[scale=1.5,black]}}}}
        }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 3/0/B, -3/0/C} 
     \tkzDrawArc[tkz arrows](A,B)(C) 
\tkzDrawSegments[tkz arrows](C,A A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it is a good solution

Comment: No need to load `TikZ` and its library because `tkz-euclide` does it

Comment: @AlainMatthesm thank you very much for this information. Actually I'm novice at using this attractive package.

Comment: @AlainMatthes, now I see, after reading your answer (+1), that  was  to much follow to OP MWE and to less investigate package investigation. I wasn't aware for `\tkzDrawSemiCircle`. I stil wonder why the first point shouldn't be negative. I need to read documentation again and again ...

Answer (score 4):

Just for comparison, here is a pure TikZ version.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[decoration={markings, mark=between positions .19 and 1 step 0.25 with {\arrow{Stealth}}}, postaction=decorate] 
    (2,0) arc (0:180:2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

To make adjustments to the arrow you can use `Stealth[<options>]`, where `<options>` can include `length=`, `width=`, `inset=`, among other things (e.g., colors). `arrows.meta` has many other arrow options as well.

Comment: I agree that it is easy with TikZ in this case but if the half circle is not at the origin and the segment is not horizontal it might be a bit more difficult.

Comment: @AlainMatthes: I suppose that's true. Though you could just rotate around any point by any angle.

Comment: yes it's the method but I prefer to write DrawSemiCircle(O,A) than to go and find the necessary angles to draw an arc. However, I have to do this to write the macros of the package!